# two string sorting by regex

Tags: java

This is my regex equation

```
\(([a-z])?([a-z])\)|\(([a-z])?([a-z])\)?\((\d)\)
```

i have two string

```
String s1="(ab)";
String s2="(ab)(1)";
```

regex is working for s1 but when i am doing with s2 it is not taking (1) into consideration.

Comment: what result you want to achieve? your reg exp looks like cumbersome

Comment: You could replace your current regex with `/\(([a-z])?([a-z])\)\((\d?)\)/`

Comment: it will not match with

Comment: it will not match with String s="(ab)" .i need to match String s1="(ab)(1)" and String s2="(ab)" .i need to sort in such a way if suppose i have two string x="(aa)" and String y="(z)"; then order should be first z ,aa or String x1="(m)(9)" and String y1="(aa)" then order should be (m)(9) ,(aa) or String x2="(q)(1)" and String y2="(q)" then order should be (q),(q)(1)

Comment: it will not match with String s="(ab)" .i need to match String s1="(ab)(1)" and String s2="(ab)" .i need to sort in such a way if suppose i have two string x="(aa)" and String y="(z)"; then order should be first z ,aa or String x1="(m)(9)" and String y1="(aa)" then order should be (m)(9) ,(aa) or String x2="(q)(1)" and String y2="(q)" then order should be (q),(q)(1)